# Запись в базу PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

Есть код,он вообще рабочий,не раз применял его,все хорошо было

```
$data = array( 'data' => "$date", 'name' => "$name", 'phone' => "$phone", 'mail' => "$mail", 'tovar' => "$tovar");  
$STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (data) values (:date)");  
$STH->execute($data);
echo "data=".$date."  name= ".$name."  phone= ".$phone."  mail= ".$mail."  tovar=".$tovar;
```

В конце `echo` все выводит,ошибок не выдает,но не записывает,но если заменить `$STH` на

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO orders ( data,name,phone,mail,tovar ) values ( '$date','$name','$phone','$mail','$tovar' )");
```

Все работает

Comment: Почитайте про bindParam и execParams ну  и правила их задавания, росписовать долго, мануал доходчивей. Но в кратце вы не задали параметры для подстановки

Comment: `Есть код,он вообще рабочий,не раз применял его` ...... `но не записывает` - вы бы определились - он рабочий и проблем нет или не записывает, тогда он не может быть рабочим, в принципе и вы не могли его не раз применять)))

Comment: Использовал на другой странице,только переменные другие и запрос другой,там все работает,пример взят отсюда https://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/

Comment: Структуру таблицы покажите? Особенно интересуют ключи и ограничения вроде `NOT NULL`

Comment: Убрал кавычки у переменных все заработало

Comment: @zkolya серьезно? кавычки? и  у вас прям все поля вставились?